# Want to remove footer when on last page in itextShap

Tags: c#, itext

Actually, I'm adding some text on a footer section like "Continued on next page..". But I want that footer should remove when on the last page. 
Here is some screenshot to describe more about my question. Thank you.

```
public partial class Footer : PdfPageEventHelper
{                
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document doc)
    {           
        Paragraph footer = new Paragraph("Continued on next page..", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));

        footer.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

        PdfPTable footerTbl = new PdfPTable(1);

        footerTbl.TotalWidth = 300;

        footerTbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(footer);

        cell.Border = 0;

        cell.PaddingLeft = 10;

        footerTbl.AddCell(cell);
        if (writer.PageNumber - 1 != writer.CurrentPageNumber)
        {
            footerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 415, 30, writer.DirectContent);
        }            
    }        
}
```

Comment: Try using writer.PageCount or doc.PageCount to see if the current page is not equal to it

Comment: @Shehab i must say that we can only set the value in it (writer.PageCount or doc.PageCount) its writeonly i have already tried this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a flag to your `Footer` class and only add the footer string as long as the flag has the original value. When you have added your last piece of content to the `Document`, right before closing it, flip that flag.

Your last document page will be finalized (and its `OnEndPage` will be called) in the course of closing the `Document`, i.e. after you changed the flag.

For example:

```
public partial class Footer : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document doc)
    {
        if (lastPage)
            return;

        Paragraph footer = new Paragraph("Continued on next page..", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));
        footer.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

        PdfPTable footerTbl = new PdfPTable(1);
        footerTbl.TotalWidth = 300;
        footerTbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(footer);
        cell.Border = 0;
        cell.PaddingLeft = 10;
        footerTbl.AddCell(cell);
        footerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 415, 30, writer.DirectContent);
    }        

    public bool lastPage = false; 
}
```

used like this:

```
Document document = ...;
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ...);
Footer footer = new Footer();
writer.PageEvent = footer;
document.Open();
[... add content to document ...]
footer.lastPage = true;
document.Close();
```